# Window Media Player Background color in c#

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

Default background color for Windows Media Player Control is Black.
Can we change this color?

I found [on msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa451588.aspx) that DisplayBackColor property is available for Windows CE but it is not available in my winforms application.

Any other way to change it?

Comment: I'm guessing since this control uses Windows Media Player ddls, whatever the background color of your Media Player is, will be what is shown in the control.